# Can't read titleTextAttributes on appearance for UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiappearance

I am working on styling the app I'm building. I want to apply some system-wide styling (fonts) to the tab bar and then in some instances style things like colour. I'm running into two problems:

1. When you set any titleTextAttributes using `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` on an instance of a UITabBar, it immediately ignores any titleTextAttributes set on the appearance proxy (including keys that were not set on the instance, but set on the appearance proxy).

   ```
   // AppDelegate
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
           NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 20.0)!
           ], forState: .Normal)
   }

   // Later on in a ViewController that has a UITabBar
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       myTabBar.setTitleTextAttributes([
           NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()
           ], forState: .Normal)

       // Tab bar items now have blue text, but Helvetica Neue font
       // We've lost the appearance proxy font (Lato-Regular)
   }
   ```
2. In order to fix (1) I was just going to copy the titleTextAttributes from the appearance proxy and then overwrite them with whatever attributes I wanted to apply on the instance. Eg.

   ```
   // AppDelegate
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
           NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 20.0)!
           ], forState: .Normal)
   }

   // Later on in a ViewController that has a UITabBar
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       var attributes = UITabBarItem.appearance().titleTextAttributesForState(state) ?? [NSObject: AnyObject]()

       assert(attributes.count > 0, "Could not read titleTextAttributes set on appearance proxy!")
   }
   ```

This is most annoying because you can read appearance proxy values on UINavigationBar just fine.

Any ideas?